# Why cumulative integration incorrect magnitude

Tags: calculus

I am trying to test a scipy integration funciton in phython.  I'm using the "cumulative_trapezoid()" function from the scipy.integrate module.  I think I am missing something obvious, but can't figure out what it is.  I am integrating a cosine wave and the results correctly represents a sine wave, but with the wrong magnitude.  I thought my sinewave output should have the same magnitude as my cosine wave input, but it doesn't.

Below is my code:

```
def test(self):

        x = np.linspace(0, 5, 5001)
        y = 1.0 * np.cos(10.0 * x)
        
        print(f"len x: {len(x)}")
        print(f"len y: {len(y)}")

        int_res = integrate.cumulative_trapezoid(y, x, initial=0)

        plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot(x, y, 'b')

        plt.plot(x, int_res, 'r')

        plt.show()
```

The input and output are shown in blue and red plots respectively.

[Input and output waveform plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3LyS.jpg)

My goal was to do a simple test to show that when I integrate a cosine wave I get a sine wave that oscillates between 1 and -1, but instead it is severely attenuated.

So, to state my question:

1. Why am I seeing the attenuation in the magnitude of the output sine wave when using cumulative integration?
2. How would I go about fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: `1.0 * np.cos(10.0 * x)` means you are integrating $\cos(10x)$ with respect to $x$.  This is $\frac{1}{10}\sin(10x)$, so is attenuated by a factor of ten.  You could just integrate `1.0 * np.cos(x)`.

Comment: Thank you very much!